# How can I change the dimension of a cube with Python?

Tags: python

I have made the below in order to create a cube by giving different X, Y, Z values, but when I give for example (6,3,2) I don't receive 6 blocks on X-axis, 3 blocks on Y-axis, and 2 blocks on the Z-axis, but I received a cube 6x6x4, why?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
def make(X,Y,Z):
     x, y, z = np.indices((X,Y,Z))
    cube2 = (x==0) & (y==0) & (z==0)
    for i in range (X):
         for j in range (Y):
             for k in range(Z):
              cube1 = (x==i) & (y==j) & (z==k)
              cube2 = cube2|cube1
          
    colors = np.ones(cube2.shape, dtype=object)
    from matplotlib import cm
    for i in range (X):
         for j in range (Y):
             for k in range(Z):
                 if 0<i<=3:
                     colors[i][j][k] = cm.gray(((i+j+k)/X),alpha=0.8)
                 elif 3<i<=6:
                     colors[i][j][k] = cm.winter(((i+j+k)/Y),alpha=0.8)
                 else:
                     colors[i][j][k] = cm.copper(((i+j+k)/Z),alpha=0.8)
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    ax.voxels(cube2, facecolors=colors, edgecolor=None)

    plt.show()

make(6,3,2,)
```

I also need your help with something else. I have created a bezier line according to the code.

```
#bezier line 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
A = np.array([10,20])
B = np.array([15,8])
C = np.array([8,22])
A = A.reshape(2,1)
B = B.reshape(2,1)
C = C.reshape(2,1)
t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.1).reshape(1,-1)
P0 = A * t + (1 - t) * B
P1 = B * t + (1 - t) * C
Pfinal = P0 * t + (1 - t) * P1
x=np.transpose(Pfinal)
x1= x[:, 0]
print(x1)
plt.plot(x1)
```

Is it possible to implement this to the above first code in order to choose different colors instead of what I have done in the if statement? For example, on the Z axis at the right of this bezier line to have cm.winter colors, at the left cm.copper or something similar.

Comment: I have seen that if I write cube1 = (x==i) & (y==j) & (z==k/2) then I have what I need . Is that ok? I am new to coding and I try to learn

Comment: why did you tag this as color and bezier? Those have _nothing_ to do with your actual question. Also, did you read the description for the "cube" tag? Because I'm pretty sure you didn't (your question is not about OLAP cube): welcome to Stackoverflow, please read the posting guidelines over on [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Honestly speaking I didn't understand your comment

Answer (score 0):

Your code produces the expected plots. I don't see a problem. This is not an answer but a means of showing you the plot I get with your code.  What are you looking for?

```
make(6,3,2)
```

[image]

Comment: well, when I have in make(6,3,2) on Y and on Z axis I have 6 and 6  squares and not 3 and 2 as I wanted. I have seen that if I write 
cube1 = (x==i) & (y==j) & (z==k/2) , that means instead of k  I use k/2 or I can use k/5 and so on then I have what I need. My question is if there is any other better way to do this, perhaps a while loop? I tried to do something with while loop but I failed

Comment: It looks to me that you have 2 squares on the z axis here (look at black and brown) and 3 on the y axis (look at the shades of gray) as desired.

Comment: Sorry to bother you but I am new to coding. What I want to do actually is, with make for example (10,10,1) to have a square with one layer on Z-axis. With (10,10,2) to have a square with two layers on Z axis and so on until have (10,10,10) which is a cube and of course each time to have the plot from (10,10,1) - (10,10,2) - (10,10,3) up to (10,10,10), that is 10 plots. In what I have done I have always a cube and not a square that each time that I increase z from 1 up to 10 to have a different square until to create the cube